# choose multiple items from list box

Tags: ms-access

Access 2007 How do I allow the user to pick multiple items from a dropdown or list box?
I can use either.  Example, I add a list box to my form and make it bound to a field from the query the form was made from.  Now the user needs to be able to pick 2-3 of the values in the list box.

I know that in the listbox properties (Multi Select) I can pick simple or Extended, but this does not save the choices.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Access MDB database format, I don't believe it's possible to have a bound list box which is also multi-select.  (Edit: Testing showed me it is possible to set the multi-select property ... but nothing gets stored in the bound field ... so it's not useful.)  Which of multiple selected values should the db engine store?

Since you have Access 2007, you can use ACCDB format, and you might be able to have a multi-select list box if it's bound to a multi-value field.  However, multi-value fields are too similar to lookup fields, and lookup fields are evil. ([The Evils of Lookup Fields in Tables](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)).

If it were me, I would choose a different approach for the user interface.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion? I just need to allow the users to pick multiple items from a list or dropdown.  Do I need to create a seperate table to capture multi choices and use a popup to pick from?

Comment: Use an unbound list box, and VBA code to examine ItemsSelected property after selections made.  I don't understand specifically what you will do with those selections; maybe revise your question to include more details about what you're hoping to accomplish.

Comment: I would vote for a JOIN table and then you can use a simple subform to edit it.