# Combo Box with multiple selections clicking ok

Tags: ms-access-2007

In access the multi combo box that I have requires me to click okay to add the selections to the box. Is there VB code to make it to where when you check beside the selections it automatically adds them to the box when you leave it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint with this database, add the `SharePoint` tag to this post.

If you are NOT using SharePoint, my research indicates you should not use a multi-valued combo box.

- [Reference 1](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/multivalued-fields.html)
- [Reference 2](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/guide-to-multivalued-fields-HA001233722.aspx)
- [Reference 3](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/i-have-a-multi-value-combo-box-in-a-table/040307a0-638b-4ffc-b7e5-489e4ba37627)
- [Reference 4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7045212/122139)

It's one of the those features provided by Access that tries to offer a shortcut while undercutting good database design.  The original classic is the [Lookup Field.](http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm)

If you still want to use this feature, VBA might let you smooth the user experience using 
`DoCmd.SetWarnings.False` and (later) `DoCmd.SetWarnings.True`.

Comment: Honestly this part of my form doesn't have any real code for it I was hoping I could do this through just establishing an event. It is just a combobox that allows multiple selections.

Comment: What kind of ComboBox is this? Access combboxes do not have a MutiSelect property - ListBoxes do. What do you mean by "checking beside"? And if you have to click a button then presumably there is some code behind that button?

Comment: O yeh, THAT'S what was bothering me!  +1 and a smile